# TV show featuring a space station or satellite with a rotating ring that eventually jammed

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember this fascinating scene from the mid-80s. I only caught the last part of the episode. The space station (or it may have been a manned satellite) was in orbit around either Earth, or an Earth-like planet. It was long and tubular, and featured a prominent torus ring that rotated around the midriff.

Inside the vehicle, we saw the inner surface of the ring rotating around the stationary habitable zone, studded with control panels and handwheels - until, that is, the ring was jammed by an explosion and stopped. Next shot - exterior, and the vehicle was now tumbling out of control with the ring now stalled.

Answer (score 3):

I can remember a scene like that from Moonraker as well, did the station look like this: [Moonraker station](http://everyjamesbondmovie.com/img/pics/moonraker/space-station.jpg)?

Aside from Doctor Who I do not recall there being many other SF series with space wheel type of stations... I think [Star Cops](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088613/) had one and maybe [Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092329/) but it's production value was low.

[Jupiter Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Moon) was a station and things were always falling off and apart from it, you can actually find that series on Hulu, but it might be a little later then what you were looking for as is [Space Precinct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Precinct), which had a [station](http://johnkennethmuir.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/precinct3.jpg) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you're remembering a scene from the James Bond film "Moonraker" (1979)? Afraid I can't find a decent reference describing it, but IIRC Bond hits the Emergency Stop button on Drax's spinning space station and brings it to a halt, complete with lots of momentum-induced carnage.

Comment: Thanks for all the very prompt answers! You guys are great!

Comment: If the right answer was one of the above, pls vote it as correct. If you discovered the right answer on your own, please put in your own answer and vote it as correct. We're always curious to find out what it was, and others may come along with the same question and find the answer you got useful.